# No sound output over HDMI in 17.04 Lenovo P50

Tags: sound, hdmi, 17.04

Tried everything, with no success. Downgrade? 16.10 worked out of the box

Comment: If you tried **everything**, then there is nothing left to try... How about listing what you tried and then see where to go from there.